# Отсутствует интернет (ethernet) на линукс, а также проблемы с клавиатурой и мышкой

Tags: linux, ethernet

Недавно заменил материнскую плату и процессор. С того момента на операционных системах, который были установлены (Windows 10 и Kali Linux) перестал работать интернет (`ethernet`).

Переустановил виндовс, и на нём всё заработало.

Переустановил также и кали линукс. Интернет (ethernet) на нём заработал, но появилась проблема: при отключении и последующем включении клавиатуры или мыши система больше не получает от них сигнал (или, может, не распознаёт. не знаю). На винде такой проблемы нет.

Пробовал устанавливать убунту и линукс минт. Но на них всё гораздо хуже: интернета (ethernet) нет, а проблема с клавиатурой и мышкой, как на кали линукс, есть.

Вывод `ip a` с кали линукс (где интернет есть):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:a8:17:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.177/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 5148sec preferred_lft 5148sec
    inet6 fe80::79ce:620c:88de:8e4c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Вывод `ip a` с линукс минт (где интернета нет):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Вывод `inxi -SN` с кали линукс:

```
System:    Host: kali Kernel: 5.10.0-kali7-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 
           Distro: Kali GNU/Linux 2021.2 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169
```

Вывод `inxi -SN` с линукс минт:

```
System:
  Host: mnt Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.5 
  Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: N/A
```

Вывод `lsmod` с кали линукс:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
exfat                  81920  1
uas                    32768  0
usb_storage            81920  2 uas
btrfs                1564672  0
blake2b_generic        20480  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              122880  1 btrfs
ufs                    94208  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               126976  0
hfs                    73728  0
cdrom                  73728  2 hfsplus,hfs
minix                  45056  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   212992  0
xfs                  1773568  0
libcrc32c              16384  2 btrfs,xfs
dm_mod                163840  0
rfkill                 28672  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
nls_ascii              16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    86016  2 msdos,vfat
snd_hda_intel          57344  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
soundwire_intel        45056  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
snd_soc_core          315392  1 soundwire_intel
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
soundwire_cadence      36864  1 soundwire_intel
snd_hda_codec         172032  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
soundwire_bus          90112  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_pcm               135168  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
joydev                 28672  0
snd_timer              49152  1 snd_pcm
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd               114688  0
snd                   110592  16 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
ccp                   106496  1 kvm_amd
soundcore              16384  1 snd
rng_core               16384  1 ccp
sp5100_tco             20480  0
k10temp                16384  0
watchdog               28672  1 sp5100_tco
sg                     36864  0
kvm                   917504  1 kvm_amd
pcspkr                 16384  0
evdev                  28672  14
acpi_cpufreq           32768  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
efi_pstore             16384  0
rapl                   20480  0
fuse                  167936  3
sunrpc                663552  1
configfs               57344  1
efivarfs               16384  1
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                53248  2
ext4                  921600  1
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  151552  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
sd_mod                 61440  6
t10_pi                 16384  1 sd_mod
crc_t10dif             20480  1 t10_pi
crct10dif_generic      16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   147456  2 usbhid,hid_generic
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crct10dif_common       16384  3 crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif,crct10dif_pclmul
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  3
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
nouveau              2326528  8
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
video                  53248  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   114688  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        274432  1 nouveau
ahci                   40960  3
aesni_intel           368640  0
libaes                 16384  1 aesni_intel
r8169                 102400  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
xhci_pci               20480  0
libahci                45056  1 ahci
cec                    61440  1 drm_kms_helper
realtek                24576  1
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
xhci_hcd              307200  1 xhci_pci
libata                290816  2 libahci,ahci
mdio_devres            16384  1 r8169
i2c_piix4              28672  0
drm                   618496  7 drm_kms_helper,ttm,nouveau
libphy                151552  3 r8169,mdio_devres,realtek
usbcore               323584  5 xhci_hcd,usbhid,usb_storage,xhci_pci,uas
scsi_mod              262144  5 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sg
usb_common             16384  2 xhci_hcd,usbcore
wmi                    36864  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
gpio_generic           16384  1 gpio_amdpt
button                 24576  1 nouveau
```

Вывод `lsmod` с линукс минт:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
input_leds             16384  0
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
joydev                 24576  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
btrfs                1257472  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
zstd_compress         167936  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              16384  1 btrfs
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  2 uas
nouveau              1949696  13
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
video                  49152  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 nouveau
aesni_intel           372736  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   491520  6 drm_kms_helper,ttm,nouveau
i2c_piix4              28672  0
r8169                  90112  0
realtek                24576  0
ahci                   40960  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt
```

Вывод `dmesg | grep r8169` с кали линукс:

```
[    3.089021] libphy: r8169: probed
[    3.089158] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8125B, 18:c0:4d:a8:17:95, XID 641, IRQ 43
[    3.089159] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   26.511572] r8169 0000:07:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw
[   26.536095] RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-700:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-700:00, irq=IGNORE)
[   26.700721] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[   28.226912] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

Вывод `dmesg | grep r8169` с линукс минт:

```
[    2.960004] r8169 0000:07:00.0: unknown chip XID 641
```

Comment: по сетевой карте см. обсуждение в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298762/Нет-интернета-ethernet)... по клавиатуре — через что они подключены? если через что-то нормальное вроде usb (`lsudb`, а также `lsusb -t` до  после в студию) или ps/2, то это достаточно странно...  могу предложить посмотреть лог ядра при переподключени через ssh или в системном журнале после перезагрузки, а также лог иксов (подразумевая, что ты их используешь) ЗЫ: продолжение обсуждение связанного вопроса без ссылки на предыдущий — дурной тон ИМХО...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ок, проблема с клавой и мышкой была не проблемой, просто линукс почему-то долго их распознаёт. Через некоторое время они начинают работать. Хоть это очень странно.

Comment: нум... это всё равно необычно... но путь для отладки тот же, что и выше...

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил выводов касательно интернета.

Comment: ок... модуль грузится, но он не привязывается к устройству... так что самое интересное всё равно в `dmesg` — там почти наверняка есть сообщение об ошибке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил выводов. Кстати, `modprobe r8169`, кажется, ничего не дал.

Comment: значит у тебя в сетевой карте всё же чип `8125b`, а не `8125a`... его поддержку добавили только в ядре 5.9 (согласно [исходникам](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc1/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169_main.c))... отсюда и проблемы... т.е. это один из тех немногих случаев, когда правильным действием будет обновить ядро, но как это правильно (или наиболее просто) сделать на бубунте мне сказать сложно... я бы добавил репозиторий более свежей версии в apt с пониженным приоритетом (что на debian'ах делается через жопу) и установил бы пакет с ядром из него...

Comment: а можешь просто использовать не-lts ubuntu 21.04... кроме того тебе понадобится пакет linux-firmware с соответствующим содержимым...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну в данном случае речь о линукс минте. "я бы добавил репозиторий более свежей версии в apt с пониженным приоритетом и установил бы пакет с ядром из него" - я без понятия, как это сделать). То есть мне просто скачать не lts ubuntu? А с линукс минтом не получится? Я скачивал последнюю версию 20.1. 20.2 пока в бете.

Comment: @Fat-Zer на не-lts ubuntu 21.04 интернет есть. Спасибо огромное!